# How to get the result of elseif in php to jquery

Tags: php, jquery

**PHP**

```
$name = karlaxis;
 if ($name == "") {
     return false;
 } elseif ($name != karlaxis) {
     return false;
 } else {
     return true;
 }
```

**jQuery**

```
$.post("#name-form").attr("action").serializearray(), function(result){
    if (result == false) {
        console.log("result of the IF CONDITION");
    } elseif (result == false) { //the result of ELSEIF in php
        console.log("result of the ELSEIF CONDITION");
    } else {
        console.log("result of the ELSE CONDITION");
    }
})
```

Now, how to get the result of the `elseif`?

How to code that one?

Comment: Your jQuery code certainly has syntax errors. Please read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Karlaxis you are using multiple false in if and else if also..change one to true condition

Comment: @MCVE yeah sir I know I was just short-cutting my code. Sorry peace :)

Comment: @Gulshan how sir? Can you show me some sample?

Comment: why do you need to check three conditions in your php code? looks to me like `if($name == 'karlaxis') return true; else return false;` would do the same thing

Comment: @SayantanDas yeah sir but I want to get the result of elseif.

Answer (score 0):

If it is very important to get the result of different conditions, you can do a simple trick with your code. Rather than returning bool you may return int values like 0,1,2 where 0 is for IF, 1 is for ELSE IF, 2 is for ELSE.

php:

```
$name = karlaxis;
 if($name == ""){
   return 0;
 }elseif($name != karlaxis){
   return 1;
 }else{
  return 2;
 }
```

jquery:

```
$.post("#name-form").attr("action").serializearray(), function(result){

IF(result == 0){  
console.log("result of the IF CONDITION");
}ELSE IF(result == 1){ //the result of ELSEIF in php
console.log("result of the ELSEIF CONDITION");
}ELSE{
console.log("result of the ELSE CONDITION");
}
})
```

Comment: sir I notice the dollar sign "$" you put in the switch($result), I forgot to tell that my jquery code is in the other page and the extension name is .js not php. Will it work sir?

Comment: Ok that i had forgot to remove, i was trying to do that before for php.. Answer updated. for jquery page doesn't matter...just scope matters.. yes

Comment: okay sir thanks for the effort, ill try this one sir hope it will work!! :)